# ORACLE:- SELECT  First Names , by removing space after the first word

Tags: oracle

ORACLE:-
In the table the First Names are as follows

```
Binda  E                                                                             
Reven   O                                                                               
Drew  J                                            
ANDAL J                                                                                       
WILL Lee                                            
Chad Hardee
```

I want to select First names in the following format

```
Binda                                                                               
Reven                                                                                  
Drew                                               
ANDAL                                                                                         
WILL                                              
Chad
```

I am using the following Query, but a having no luck

```
SELECT  first_name, SUBSTR(first_name, REGEXP_INSTR('first_name','[^ ]+', 1, 1) ) FROM contact.user_names
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NVL(substr(first_name, 1, instr(first_name,' ')), first_name)

```
with t AS
    (
    SELECT 'Binda  E   ' as first_name FROM dual                                                                          
    union
    SELECT 'Reven   O  ' as first_name FROM dual                                                                             
    union
    SELECT 'Drew  J    ' as first_name FROM dual                                        
    union
    SELECT 'ANDAL J    ' as first_name FROM dual                                                                                   
    union
    SELECT 'WILL Lee   ' as first_name FROM dual                                         
    union
    SELECT 'Chad Hardee' as first_name FROM dual 
    union
    SELECT 'foobar' as first_name FROM dual 

    )
    SELECT NVL(substr(first_name, 1, instr(first_name,' ')), first_name) FROM t
    ;
```

Comment: I Used "SELECT NVL(substr(first_name, 1, instr(first_name,' ')), first_name) FROM t;"